# Is /usr/libexec/java_home still relevant on macOS?

Tags: java

I can add my java bin dir to my path in .zshrc and compile and run Java apps just fine. I can set JAVA_HOME there as well, for applications that need it. So do I need /usr/libexec/java_home for anything?

When I run java_home -V nothing shows up (looks like it doesn't know about my Java install to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java). Is it a holdover from when java was installed by default, or is there some functionality I'm missing out on by not using it?

Comment: Which macOS are you running?

Comment: @lhf I'm on Big Sur (11.1)

Comment: In El Capitan, `/usr/libexec/java_home` is a symbolic link to `System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java_home`.

Comment: java_home -V and -v works with the Oracle Java installs (also in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/)